# Lost scroll viewer functionality inside of ListBox when ListBox.Template used

Tags: wpf

I wanted to implement headers in the ListView below, and I did that via ListBox.Template, however by doing that, I have lost my default vertical scroll viewer inside of the ListBox. How can I get that back with the existing implementation. Thanks

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding HistoryDetails}" 
     MaxHeight="250"
     MinWidth="300"
     MinHeight="50"
     AlternationCount="2"
     Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="40">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col1"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col2"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Action" Margin="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Description" Margin="10" MaxWidth="600" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col1"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col2"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col3"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="col4"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Note}" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="600"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: When you create a new `ControlTemplate` for a control like this, you need to explicitly include the functionality you want.  You overrode the default `ListBox`, so some of its functionality went away.  Putting a `ScrollViewer` around your `ItemsPresenter` should get you back to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your template. Put this around your ItemsPresenter:

```
<ScrollViewer 
    x:Name="ScrollViewer"
    Margin="0"
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ItemsPresenter/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I hope this helps!